# Day Scrolling para Mês Scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa noite!

Tenho este exemplo de day scrolling que faz o usuário percorrer pelas datas do mês a cada clique tanto para frente quanto para trás. Porém, gostaria de que, em vez de a cada clique avançar o dia, ser avançado o mês para frente ou para trás. É possível?

Segue abaixo meu código:

**pagina2.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:king_app/pages/calendar/scrolling.dart';
class Pagina2 extends StatelessWidget {

  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  DateTime startDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 50));
  DateTime endDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 50));
  Map<String, Widget> widgets = Map();
  String widgetKeyFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
          child: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF11c76f),
            elevation: 0,
          ),
        ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
        child: ScrollingDayCalendar(
          startDate: startDate,
          endDate: endDate,
          selectedDate: selectedDate,
          dateStyle: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          displayDateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy",
          dateBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF11c76f),
          forwardIcon: Icons.arrow_forward,
          backwardIcon: Icons.arrow_back,
          pageChangeDuration: Duration(
            milliseconds: 700,
          ),
          widgets: widgets,
          widgetKeyFormat: widgetKeyFormat,
          noItemsWidget: Center(
            child: Text(
                "teste " ), 
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**scrolling.dart**

```
library scrolling_day_calendar;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

typedef ScrollingDayCalendarBuilder = Widget Function(
    BuildContext context,
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate,
    DateTime selectedDate,
    Function onDateChange,
    );

class ScrollingDayCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
  // first date on the pages
  final DateTime startDate;
  // last date on the pages
  final DateTime endDate;
  // the active date
  final DateTime selectedDate;
  // what to do then the date changes
  final Function onDateChange;
  // page widgets to display
  final Widget pageItems;
  // date format
  final String displayDateFormat;
  // date style
  final TextStyle dateStyle;
  // background color for date container
  final Color dateBackgroundColor;
  // forward icon
  final IconData forwardIcon;
  // back icon
  final IconData backwardIcon;
  // page change duration
  final Duration pageChangeDuration;

  final Map<String, Widget> widgets;
  final Widget noItemsWidget;
  final String widgetKeyFormat;

  ScrollingDayCalendar({
    @required this.pageItems,
    @required this.startDate,
    @required this.endDate,
    @required this.selectedDate,
    this.onDateChange,
    this.widgets,
    this.noItemsWidget,
    this.widgetKeyFormat,
    this.displayDateFormat,
    this.dateStyle,
    this.dateBackgroundColor,
    this.forwardIcon,
    this.backwardIcon,
    this.pageChangeDuration,
  });

  @override
  _ScrollingDayCalendarState createState() => _ScrollingDayCalendarState();
}

class _ScrollingDayCalendarState extends State<ScrollingDayCalendar> {
  PageController _pageController;
  int _totalPages;
  int _currentPage;
  int _previousPage;
  DateTime _selectedDate;

  _onPageChange(direction) {
    _currentPage = _pageController.page.round();

    if (_currentPage > _previousPage) {
      // went forward
      DateTime newDate = _selectedDate.add(
        Duration(days: 1),
      );

      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = newDate;
      });
    } else {
      // went back
      DateTime newDate = _selectedDate.subtract(
        Duration(days: 1),
      );

      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = newDate;
      });
    }

    _previousPage = _pageController.page.round();

    // run page update sent by user
    if (widget.onDateChange != null) {
      widget.onDateChange(direction, _selectedDate);
    }
  }

  Widget _buildPage(index) {
    if (widget.pageItems != null) {
      return widget.pageItems;
    }
    DateTime dateTime = widget.startDate;
    index = index + 1;

    dateTime = widget.startDate.add(Duration(days: index));
    String key = DateFormat(widget.widgetKeyFormat).format(dateTime);

    if (widget.widgets != null && widget.widgets.containsKey(key)) {
      return widget.widgets[key];
    }

    return widget.noItemsWidget;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // set the selected date
    _selectedDate = widget.selectedDate;

    // calculate the start page
    int startingPage =
    _selectedDate.difference(widget.startDate).inDays.floor();

    setState(() {
      // set the total number of pages based on start date and end date
      _totalPages = widget.endDate.difference(widget.startDate).inDays.floor();

      // set starting page
      _pageController = PageController(initialPage: startingPage);

      // set previous page
      _previousPage = startingPage;
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold (
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 60.0,
                width: 60.0,
                color: widget.dateBackgroundColor != null
                    ? widget.dateBackgroundColor
                    : Colors.red,
                child: Center(
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _pageController.previousPage(
                        duration: widget.pageChangeDuration != null
                            ? widget.pageChangeDuration
                            : Duration(microseconds: 700),
                        curve: Curves.easeIn,
                      );
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      widget.backwardIcon == null
                          ? Icons.arrow_back
                          : widget.backwardIcon,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  color: widget.dateBackgroundColor != null
                      ? widget.dateBackgroundColor
                      : Colors.red,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        DateFormat(widget.displayDateFormat != null
                            ? widget.displayDateFormat
                            : "MM/yyyy")
                            .format(_selectedDate),
                        style: widget.dateStyle != null
                            ? widget.dateStyle
                            : TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 60.0,
                width: 60.0,
                color: widget.dateBackgroundColor != null
                    ? widget.dateBackgroundColor
                    : Colors.red,
                child: Center(
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _pageController.nextPage(
                        duration: widget.pageChangeDuration != null
                            ? widget.pageChangeDuration
                            : Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        curve: Curves.easeIn,
                      );
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      widget.forwardIcon == null
                          ? Icons.arrow_forward
                          : widget.forwardIcon,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: _pageController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: _totalPages, // Can be null
              onPageChanged: (direction) => _onPageChange(direction),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return _buildPage(index);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das formas de se fazer é criar uma nova data quando clicar na seta para "trás" ou para "frente".

**Exemplo:**

Declare alguns atributos na sua classe para montar a data

```
// Depende da sua regra identificar a data inicial
// Aqui recuperei a data atual do dispositivo
DateTime data = DateTime.now();

int dia;
int mes;
int ano;
DateTime novaData;
```

No initState() preencha os atributos de dia, mês e ano utilizando como referência a data inicial que você planejar utilizar. Aqui no caso é com base na data atual.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  dia = data.day;
  mes = data.month;
  ano = data.year;
}
```

Crie um método para montar a data

```
_montarNovaData(){
  setState(() {
    novaData = DateTime(ano, mes, dia);    
  });
}
```

Dentro da função de clique do botão implemente uma pequena lógica para somar o dia e o ano quando clicar no botão `>` e outra quando o clique for no botão `<` e em ambas faça a solicitação para que a tela seja redesenhada chamando o método de montagem da nova data. Como ele tem o setState() dentro dele a tela vai ser redesenhada.

```
// Função que passa para o próximo mês
_clickProximoMes(){
  if(mes == 12){
    ano++;
    mes = 1;        
  } else {
    mes++;      
  }

  _montarNovaData();
}

// Função que passa para o mês anterior
_clickMesAnterior(){
  if(mes == 1){
    ano--;
    mes = 12;
  } else {                   
    mes--;
  }

  _montarNovaData();
}
```

Com essa `novaData` o que precisa é somente utilizar no local que está montando seu `Widget`.

Essa é uma das maneiras de implementar o comportamento desejado. Não cheguei a rodar o código em um projeto mas é uma estrutura semelhante a uma implementação que fiz em um app que já está em produção e tem funcionado tranquilamente pra mim.

Sobre a lógica das funções de mês seguinte e anterior, poderia ser melhorada colocando tratamento para ano negativo por exemplo ou até mesmo limitando a um determinado período mas aí tudo fica a seu critério.

No mais acredito que com isso é possível que faça a adaptação ao seu código.

Comment: Consegui implementar sua solução, apenas tive que fazer uma modificação no if pois estava avançado tanto o mês quanto o ano, muito obrigado!

Comment: @denis de fato a lógica de alterar o ano estava incorreta. Editei a resposta para que fique correta fazendo a mudança de ano somente quando pular de dezembro pra janeiro e de janeiro pra dezembro. Obrigado pelo feedback.